# Why isn't netbeans highlighting syntax errors?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

For some reason netbeans has stopped highlighting syntax and other errors. Why, and how do I fix it?

I am working with java classes. I have completely removed netbeans from my linux system and reinstalled, but still the same problem. So I also changed to another project. It does not happen on a new project. So it must be somehow related to the project

Netbeans is 8.2, the project is JavaEE, Maven based. All syntax errors are not being highlighted

Comment: [1] I doubt if anyone can help based on the limited information you have provided. Is it possible to update your post with a couple of screen shots demonstrating that some syntax errors are being ignored in the offending project, yet detected in another project? [2] What are the exact versions of NetBeans and Java that you are using? [3] Provide more details on the offending project: Spring? Maven? Web? Java EE? Source/binary format? Java platform? Are any syntax errors at all being detected? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem related to the project rather than netbeans. A delete and clone from repository solved the problem.